# Collapsable List seems to be preventing menu list from working

Tags: javascript, html, collapsable

I am trying to work on my program's website. I put in a collapsable list on one of my pages. The top of my pages has a menu to go everywhere on the website. However, on the pages where I put in the collapsable, the menu dropdowns don't work. Can anyone help? Here's my code from one of the pages and the link to the actual page: http://ladyhighlanderbasketball.net/history/Season%20Records.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Season Records</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/superfish.css">
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="../js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
       <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
         <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
           <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
        </a>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!--==============================header=================================-->
<div class="main">
     <div class="head">      
         <header>

           <div class="nav-logo">
               <div class="logo-search-form">
                     <h1><a href="/index.html"></a></h1>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
               <nav> 
                 <ul class="sf-menu">
                     <li class="current" id="first-li"><a href="/index.html">HOME</a>

       </li>
                      <li id="id-2"><a href="#">TEAM</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="/current/varsityroster.pdf">Varsity Roster</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/the-woodlands-highlanders-(the-woodlands,tx)/girls-basketball/home.htm">Varsity Stats</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/current/jvroster.pdf">JV Roster</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">Freshman Roster</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://mccullough.conroeisd.net/athletics-1/basketball-girls">McCullough Jr. High</a></li>
                          <li><a href="current/coaches.pdf">Coaching Staff</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>
                      <li id="id-3"><a href="#">SCHEDULE</a>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="current/1718finalschedule.pdf">Schedule</a></li>
                          <li><a href="current/results.html">Scores/Results</a></li>
                 <li><a href="current/tournbrackets.html">Tournament Brackets</a></li>
                  <li><a href="current/scrimmages.html">Scrimmages</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>

                     <li id="id-4"><a href="#">MEDIA</a>
                     <ul>
                     <li><a href="/media/news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/media/lonspictures.html">Lon's Photography</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="/media/PhotoGallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/media/links.html">Links</a></li>   
                     </ul>
                     </li>

                      <li id="id-5"><a href="#">HISTORY</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="/history/Yearly History.html">Yearly Accolades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/history/Career Records.html">Career Records</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/history/Season Records.html">Season Records</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/history/Off Season Records.html">Off Season Records</a></li>
                          </ul>
                     </li>

                      <li id="id-7"><a href="contact/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li> 
                   <li id="id-8"><a href="club/lhbbc.html">BOOSTER CLUB</a></li> 


                 </ul>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
             </nav>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
      <!--the end of head-->
        <!--==============================content================================-->
<section id="content" class="top-0">         
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-block-left">
          <h2 class="padd-h2-2-1"><strong>LADY HIGHLANDER BASKETBALL</strong> HISTORY</h2>
          <span class="font-16 txt_uppercase bold">Program history/records</span>
          <div class="div-tableh1 top-2-1">
              <table width="664">
                 <tr>
                     <td class="board-td" align="center"><a href="../history/Yearly History.html">Historical Yearly Accolades</a></td>
                <td class="board-td" align="center"><a href="../history/Career Records.html">Career Records</a></td>
                <td class="board-td" align="center"><a href="../history/Season Records.html">Season Records</a></td>
                <td class="board-td" align="center"><a href="../history/Off Season Records.html">Off Season Records</a></td>
                </tr>  
            </table>
          </div>
        <p>
            <span class="font-16 txt_uppercase bold dis-block top-0-1 bot-0">Season Records</span>
        </p>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1">Total Points</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body"><strong>700 Point Club</strong></div>
                <div class="panel-body">1. Amanda Anderson - 712 points (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body"><strong>500 Point Club</strong></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">2. Amanda Anderson - 597 points (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Kelsey Lang - 584 points (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Anna Strickland - 560 points (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Nicole Iademarco - 535 points (2013-2014)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Kelsey Lang - 501 points (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body"><strong>400 Point Club</strong></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Mia Ajekwu - 492 points (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Megan Valicevic - 470 points (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Brittney Reed - 466 points (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Nicole Iademarco - 447 points (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">11. Heather Anderson - 427 points (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body"><strong>300 Point Club</strong></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Amanda Anderson - 394 points (2006-2007)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">13. Payton Walker - 386 points (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">14. Anna Strickland - 365 points (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Anna Strickland - 360 points (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">16. Emma Warnsman - 354 points (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">17. Brittney Reed - 351 points (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">18. Megan (McDougald) Storms - 344 points (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">19. Payton Walker - 342 points (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">20. Courtney Clark - 341 points (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">21. Paige Bradley - 335 points (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">22. Brittany Caporale - 319 points (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">23. Casey Walker - 313 points (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">24. Melissa Richardson - 312 points (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">25. Sarah Seefeldt - 310 points (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">26. Sarah Seefeldt - 303 points (2007-2008)</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1">Highest Points Per Game Average</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">1. Amanda Anderson - 19.24 PPG (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">2. Nicole Iademarco - 18.45 PPG (2013-2014)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Amanda Anderson - 17.56 PPG (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Kelsey Lang - 16.22 PPG (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Anna Strickland - 16.00 PPG (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Mia Ajekwu - 15.38 PPG (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Emma Warnsman - 14.80 PPG (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Kelsey Lang - 14.31 PPG (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Megan Valicevic - 14.24 PPG (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Brittney Reed - 14.12 PPG (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">11. Amanda Anderson - 13.13 PPG (2006-2007)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Heather Anderson - 12.94 PPG (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">13. Nicole Iademarco - 12.42 PPG (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">14. Anna Strickland - 11.41 PPG (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Payton Walker - 11.35 PPG (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">16. Anna Strickland - 11.25 PPG (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">17. Megan (McDougald) Storms - 11.10 PPG (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">18. Megan Valicevic - 11.06 PPG (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">19. Payton Walker - 10.69 PPG (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">20. Brittney Reed - 10.64 PPG (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">21. Paige Bradley - 10.47 PPG (2010-2011)</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree1">Most 3 Pt FG (minimum 30)</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">1. Nicole Iademarco - 70 makes in 188 attempts for 37.2% (2013-2014)</div>
                <div class="panel-body">2. Courtney Clark - 57 makes in 142 attempts for 40.1% (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Melissa Richardson - 55 makes in 145 attempts for 37.9% (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Julia Glandt - 50 makes in 171 attempts for 29.2% (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Ashlyn Hargraves - 46 makes in 124 attempts for 37.1% (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Kaitlyn Westfall - 43 makes in 142 attempts for 30.3% (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Melissa Richardson - 42 makes in 118 attempts for 35.6% (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Paige Bradley - 41 makes in 125 attempts for 32.8% (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Aaliyah Wheatfall - 41 makes in 134 attempts for 30.6% (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Nicole Iademarco - 38 makes in 119 attempts for 31.9% (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">11. Courtney Clark - 34 makes in 125 attempts for 27.2% (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Heather Anderson - 33 makes in 94 attempts for 35.1% (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Amber Terry - 33 makes in 131 attempts for 25.2% (2014-2015)</div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseFour1">Most FT (minimum 75 made)</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFour1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">1. Amanda Anderson - 157 makes in 197 attempts for 79.7% (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">2. Payton Walker - 151 makes in 195 attempts for 77.4% (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Anna Strickland - 150 makes in 198 attempts for 75.8 (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Payton Walker - 143 makes in 171 attempts for 83.6% (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Megan Valicevic - 121 makes in 156 attempts for 77.6% (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Megan Valicevic - 116 makes in 152 attempts for 76.3% (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Emma Warnsman - 107 makes in 138 attempts for 77.5% (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Brittney Reed - 107 makes in 180 attempts for 59.4% (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Amanda Anderson - 106 makes in 144 attempts for 73.6% (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Heather Anderson - 90 makes in 135 attempts for 66.7% (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Luisa De La Rosa - 90 makes in 156 attempts for 57.7% (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Mia Ajekwu - 88 makes in 129 attempts for 68.2% (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">13. Megan Crawford - 85 makes in 120 attempts for 70.8% (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">14. Brittney Reed - 84 makes in 131 attempts for 64.1% (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Aaliyah Wheatfall - 83 makes in 114 attempts for 72.8% (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">16. Megan (McDougald) Storms - 82 makes in 115 attempts for 71.3% (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">17. Nicole Iademarco - 79 makes in 107 attempts for 73.8% (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">18. Payton Walker - 75 makes in 104 attempts for 72.1% (2013-2014)</div>

              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseFive1">Most Rebounds (minimum 200 rebounds)</a></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFive1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">1. Amanda Anderson - 403 rebounds (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">2. Anna Strickland - 377 rebounds (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Kelsey Lang - 350 rebounds (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Payton Walker - 322 rebounds (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Anna Strickland - 315 rebounds (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Anna Strickland - 296 rebounds (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">7. Luisa De La Rosa - 294 rebounds (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Julia Requarth - 286 rebounds (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Payton Walker - 278 rebounds (2014-2015)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">10. Luisa De La Rosa - 278 rebounds (2015-2016)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">11. Kelsey Lang - 277 rebounds (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Mia Ajekwu - 275 rebounds (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">13. Amanda Anderson - 271 rebounds (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">14. Luisa De La Rosa - 269 rebounds (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Amanda Anderson - 238 rebounds (2006-2007)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Kelsey Lang - 238 rebounds (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">17. Anna Strickland - 231 rebounds (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">18. Casey Walker - 224 rebounds (2001-2002)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">19. Sarah Seefeldt - 220 rebounds (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">20. Brittney Reed - 217 rebounds (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">21. Brittney Reed - 213 rebounds (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">22. Sarah Seefeldt - 203 rebounds (2008-2009)</div>
          </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseSix1">Most Assists (minimum 100 assists)</a></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseSix1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">1. Paige Bradley - 260 assists (2011-2012)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">2. Brittany Caporale - 256 assists (2007-2008)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">3. Paige Bradley - 233 assists (2010-2011)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">4. Paige Bradley - 211 assists (2009-2010)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">5. Nicole Iademarco - 179 assists (2012-2013)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">6. Paulina Bremmer - 160 assists (2013-2014)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">7. Brittany Caporale - 115 assists (2006-2007)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">8. Brittany Caporale - 112 assists (2005-2006)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">9. Megan Crawford - 111 assists (2002-2003)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">10. Megan Valicevic - 105 assists (2002-2003)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">10. Madison McKinstrey - 105 assists (2008-2009)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">12. Amanda Anderson - 102 assists (2008-2009)</div>
                      <div class="panel-body">13. Ashlyn Hargraves - 101 assists (2011-2012)</div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion1" href="#collapseSeven1">Most Steals (minimum 60 steals)</a></h4>  
                  </div>
              <div id="collapseSeven1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">1. Amanda Anderson - 112 steals (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">2. Nicole Iademarco - 105 steals (2012-2013)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">3. Megan Crawford - 101 steals (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">4. Brittany Caporale - 99 steals (2005-2006)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">5. Paige Bradley - 98 steals (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Molly Missimer - 97 steals (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">6. Paulina Bremmer - 97 steals (2013-2014)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">8. Paige Bradley - 94 steals (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Brittany Caporale - 93 steals (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">9. Nicole Iademarco - 93 steals (2013-2014)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">11. Anna Strickland - 87 steals (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Molly Missimer - 85 steals (2008-2009)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">12. Paige Bradley - 85 steals (2009-2010)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">14. Melissa Richardson - 80 steals (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Courtney Clark - 74 steals (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">15. Luisa De La Rosa - 74 steals (2016-2017)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">17. Anna Strickland - 72 steals (2010-2011)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">18. Jaymie Harner - 71 steals (2002-2003)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">19. Ashlyn Hargraves - 69 steals (2011-2012)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">20. Jaymie Harner - 66 steals (2003-2004)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">20. Megan Valicevic - 66 steals (2004-2005)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">22. Amanda Anderson - 64 steals (2007-2008)</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">22. Kristin Mahoney - 64 steals (2013-2014)</div>
                  </div>

              </div>

<div class="div-table top-6-1"></div>
      </div>
              </div>
                 <!--the end of left block-->  
      <div class="main-block-right bord-left-none-1">

    <div class="inner-1">
              <h2 class="padd-h2-2 bord-bot-4"><strong>COLLEGIATE</strong> <span>PLAYERS</span></h2>
 <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
                <img src="collegepics/1718glandt.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
                <div class="extra-wrap">
                    <a href="southwesternpirates.com/sports/w-baskbl/2017-18/bios/glandt_julia_4z48" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Julia Glandt</a>
                    <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Southwestern University<br>
                    Freshman<br>
                    Guard</font></p>
                </div>
              </div>
<div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
                <img src="collegepics/1617iademarco.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
                <div class="extra-wrap">
                   <a href="http://www.riceowls.com/sports/w-baskbl/mtt/nicole_iademarco_973449.html" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Nicole Iademarco</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Rice  University<br>
                     RS Junior<br>
                  Guard/Forward</font></p>
                  </div>
            </div>
               <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
                <img src="collegepics/1718mahoney.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
               <div class="extra-wrap">
                   <a href="http://www.icgaels.com/roster.aspx?rp_id=4393" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Kristin Mahoney</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Iona<br>
                     Senior<br>
                 Guard</font></p>
                </div>
          </div>
           <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
            <img src="collegepics/1617musso.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
           <div class="extra-wrap">
              <a href="http://athletics.concordia.edu/roster.aspx?rp_id=4012&path=wbball" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Meghan Musso</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Concordia<br>
                     Sophomore<br>
              Point Guard</font></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrapper-extra block-1 last-bot">
            <img src="collegepics/1617terry.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
              <div class="extra-wrap">
                   <a href="http://cometsports.utdallas.edu/roster.aspx?rp_id=2373" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Amber Terry</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">UT-Dallas<br>
                     Junior<br>
                     Guard
                </font></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
            <img src="collegepics/1718_aaliyah_wheatfall.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
           <div class="extra-wrap">
                   <a href="http://www.jacksonville-college.edu/womens-basketball" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Aaliyah Wheatfall</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">University of the Southwest<br>
                     Junior<br>
              Guard</font></p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <h2 class="padd-h2-2 bord-bot-4"><strong>PRO</strong> <span>PLAYERS</span></h2>


           <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
            <img src="collegepics/1617bradley.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
           <div class="extra-wrap">
              <a href="http://basketball.eurobasket.com/player/Paige-Bradley/Germany/BC_Pharmaserv_Marburg/267733?Women=1" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Paige Bradley</a>
                   <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Marburg<br>
                     Germany DBBL<br>
              Guard</font></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrapper-extra block-1">
            <img src="collegepics/1718lang.jpg" alt="" class="fleft top-1 left right">
            <div class="extra-wrap">
                <a href="http://basketball.eurobasket.com/player/Kelsey-Lang/Russia/Dynamo-Moscow/307360?Women=1" class="col hov bold dis-inblock top-1-1">Kelsey Lang</a>
                <p class="line-h-18 top-1-2"><font color="#848282">Moscow Dynamo<br>
                    Russa PBL<br>
                    Center</font></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>  <!--the end of right-block-->
      <div class="clear"></div> 
      <aside>
         <div class="container_12">
           <div class="clear"></div>
        </div> 
      </aside>
    <!--the end of wrapper-->
    <!--==============================footer=================================-->        
    <footer>
        <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_12">
                     <p>www.LadyHighlanderBasketball.net &copy; 2013<a href="../index-6.html"></a></p>
                </div>

          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </footer>
</section>
    </div>  
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this file:

http://ladyhighlanderbasketball.net/js/tms-0.4.1.js

is not included in the History page, but it is in other pages. This is what creates the effect.

Comment: Two things: 1) I noticed a script that is grayed out, so I took out those markers to make it active but I didn't notice the difference. 2) I'm not seeing that script in many other of my pages that actually works  with the menu effect that I'm looking for, like http://ladyhighlanderbasketball.net/club/lhbbc.html